# where is my downloaded mp3 from internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

When I download an mp3 from internet explorer it opens and I can play it but after I cant find it anywhere on my phone. Is there a downloads equivalent like in android?

Answer (score 1):

mp3 downloaded from IE or WhatsApp goes to an internal storage which is not accessible and no file manager is available to access those mp3.

However you can find those mp3 on you music player, mp3 are added automatically.

**Alternative Answer**

Use other browser such as UC Browser, that stores all the mp3 or any other data at your external SD card. And those areas are accessible by all file managers.